# Date Dependant Calculation

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I've got a (Excel) sheet with running totals of income and expenses. The data from each day is fed into a weekly running total. I also have monthly expenses that I would like to include into the weekly total expense count/profit count but don't want to put each category of monthly expenses into each day's or week's input fields.

I would like to keep the monthly expenses in it's own input field but add the data to the corresponding week the bills were paid.

I've been at this for weeks but can only find solutions that end with circular references. Bonus challanges: I'm pretty happy with the size of each input field and don't want to add any more fields nor do I want to do macros or any VBA. I really just want a formula to take care of it.

Is there a way to have Excel stop adding to a total after a certain day?

Link to the sheet. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5qCnQJhT_vkNHZlaEpnTGRtUjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I like that you actually gave us a live link to the spreadsheet, but your question on its own is a bit vague to me.  The less guesswork readers have to do, the higher the probability of getting a useful answer.

Comment: What it boils down to is that starting on Monday of week two, I would like for the "monthly expenses" to start counting toward week two's expense total without having whatever I may have paid in week one being added to it. For example, if I paid rent during week one (it doesn't really matter what day) and insurance during week two, I would like $875 to show up on week 1's expense total and $100 in week 2's expense total.  I hope that helps clear it up a bit.

Comment: I find the question even with clarification to be very vague, there doesn't seem to be any dates in your calculations, I don't know how you want to associate anything with dates to weeks if you don't have the data in the first place.

Comment: I included two days in the sheet to which I've linked. I see now I deleted the dates provided. I will fix that.

To differentiate the weeks in some of my test formulas, i've been using something along the lines of =(if *Friday's date of week 1* < *Monday's date of week 2*, do a thing, do a different thing). I've just recently thought of adding an AND operator but I still can't get the total for the first week to stay at what it would be.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are entering your expense directly into your "dashboard" am I right? E.g. the rent 875 in cell H13. If this is the case, without a date, then you can't get Excel to intelligently place the expense to the correct week report in your dashboard.

try creating an input table and all your dashboard figures should come from the input table, utilizing functions like `SUMIFS` and `SUMIF`.

Example

[image]

Then in your dashboard

formula in H13 would be `=SUMIFS(E:E,C:C,"Rent",D:D,"Check")`

formula in G4, `=SUMIFS(E:E,C:C,"Food",D:D,"Cash")`

formula in D23, `=SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,51,C:C,"Rent",D:D,"Cash")`